# Can you uninstall a gem version in gemfile?

Tags: rubygems

We're specifying a specific version of a gem in our gemfile, however a previous version which is incompatible with our app is installed.

The gemfile is used on many machines so we want an automated way to uninstall the unrequired gem.

Any way to do this?

Thanks ahead for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://www.paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/show/97-how-to-remove-a-specific-version-of-a-gem-file-in-a-specific-directory

Comment: The provided page is not available. Do you have any other solution?